# Mouse Follow Script, Cant Animate on Hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to implement script to have a div block follow my mouse, then animate it when hovering over certain links. The problem is when transforming it on hover of any objects, it starts to flash and become finicky.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/grayghostvisuals/pen/kepDb/

```
var $circle = $('.circle');
function moveCircle(e) {
TweenLite.to($circle, 0.7, {
css: {
  left: e.pageX,
  top: e.pageY
}
  });
}

$(window).on('mousemove', moveCircle);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There are no links in your example demonstrating the problem

Comment: Maybe you should show the animation code too....

Comment: Sorry about that, just one second.

Comment: Looks like that's not the problem. It's not the actual animation, but that if your not moving quickly enough, or not at a complete stop, it stops any sort of javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a z-index issue. Hover will try to check if your mouse is above your element, but it will be hovering the circle following your mouse. This pen shows how it works if you use a negative z-index for the circle, too.

You can however make your browser ignore the pointer events for the circle, removing the problem all together. I [changed your pen to add the solution](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGQGJW).

```
.element {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: You are the best! I tried messing with the z-index and it didn't do it. Setting the pointer-events to none fixed it! Thanks!